# kotlin missing methods for GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, kotlin

I'm converting part of an app to kotlin and I've a problem caused by the intellisense of Android Studio (3.5.3) not showing all methods of googleMaps

this is an example:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    map = googleMap
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true)
    map.setTrafficEnabled(true)

    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(OnMapLoadedCallback {
        if (currentMission != null) {
            drawMission()
        } else {
            drawNoMission()
        }
    })
}
```

for instance I can't see `map.setBuildingsEnabled` in intellisense, see image

[image]

but if I force to call that hidden method, the app still builds, so it's something caused by kotlin or intellisense
It may be related to the gray suggestion I got regarding property access maybe (but this isn't a property because on google maps there isn't a getBuildingsEnabled

[image]

did anyone knows how to fix this annoying problem? I don't want kotlin to hide methods that may be useful to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with ‘get’ and single-argument methods with names starting with ‘set’) are represented as properties in Kotlin.

In other words if you had a Java method `setTrafficEnabled(true)` Kotlin will provide you a property access syntax `isTrafficEnabled = true`. This is one of Kotlin advantages.

If you ignore Kotlin property access syntax and use getters and setters, it will work all the same.

Comment: mmm no isTrafficEnabled is already present on GoogleMap class and it's a get only
so this would not work. I need to set the value not to get it
I would expect instead to have a trafficEnabled property but it's not there, because googlemaps java class doesn't define a getTrafficEnabled method

Comment: @FabioAngela thats strange, I`m using GoogleMap class in my project and i just checked if 'isTrafficEnabled = true' works. You should be able to set it because GoogleMap class has method public final void 'setTrafficEnabled(boolean var1)'

Comment: I confirm, it works, the problem was I did "go to definition" while it was performing the get, accepted answer

Comment: still what confuses me is that `setIndoorEnabled` is visible with intellisense, and it seems to me that's implemented the same way as trafficEnabled

Comment: ahhh inspecting the decompiled class I see that setIndoorEnabled returns a boolean while others don't, that's why kotlink doesn't behave the same